# How to specify the 'string' data type when using Numba?

Tags: python, string, numba

Numba does not recognize the string. How can I correct the following code? Thank you!

```
@nb.jit(nb.float64(nb.float64[:], nb.char[:]), nopython=True, cache=True)
def func(x, y='cont'):
    """
    :param x: is np.array, x.shape=(n,)
    :param y: is a string, 
    :return: a np.array of same shape as x
    """
    return result
```

Answer (score 6):

The following works for Numba 0.44:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

from numba import types

@nb.jit(nb.float64[:](nb.float64[:], types.unicode_type), nopython=True, cache=True)
def func(x, y='cont'):
    """
    :param x: is np.array, x.shape=(n,)
    :param y: is a string, 
    :return: a np.array of same shape as x
    """
    print(y)
    return x
```

However, you're going to get an error if you try to run `func` with no value of `y` specified, since in your signature you're saying that the second argument is required. I tried figuring out how to handle the optional parameter (looked at `types.Omitted`), but couldn't quite figure it out. I would possibly look at not specifying a signature and leaving numba to do the proper type inference:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def func2(x, y='cont'):
    """
    :param x: is np.array, x.shape=(n,)
    :param y: is a string, 
    :return: a np.array of same shape as x
    """
    print(y)
    return x
```